# Is there a better way to generalize dbSet with the same attribute - Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, refactoring

I have a common pattern

```
bool doesLinkExist = await [DBSet]
.AnyAsync(model => model.PartId == parameters.PartId).ConfigureAwait(false);

if(doesLinkExist)
   throw exception (which has different messages)
```

[DBSet]=>Table in the database.

If I create a method it is really easy to pass the exception message but the DB set seems to be the problem as the code doesn't know that there are PartId columns in different [DBset]s/tables

What could be a way to bypass this problem and to create a common method?

Edit: In 2 words, I want to pass the [DBSet] as a parameter

This is the way that I would like this method to look like

```
private Task CheckLinkExistAsync(int idForLookUp, string errorMsg, DBSet table, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
  bool LinkExist = await table.AnyAsync(model => model.Id == idForLookUp, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);

  if(LinkExist)
     throw exception (which has different messages)
}
```

Comment: Which Entity Framework version?

Comment: @GertArnold it is **3.1.12**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried many different ways(with `dynamic` or DbSet< T>) but didn't think that I am filtering only on the ID so that's why I can just pass a `List<int>` and filter on it

```
private void CheckLinkExistsAsync(int partId, string errorMessage, List<int> idsToLookup)
    {
        bool exists = idsToLookup.Any(id => id == partId);
        if(exists)
            throw new Exception(errorMessage);
    }
```

And I call it like this

```
CheckLinkExistsAsync(parameters.PartId, "ExceptionMessage",
                await Db.Table.Select(model => model.PartId).ToListAsync(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false));
```

Answer (score 0):

Creating a method that accepts a `Func` as a parameter is probably what you're looking for.

```
        private async Task<IActionResult> CheckLinkExistsAsync(int id, string errorMessage, Func<Task<T>> func)
        {
            bool exists = await _modelRepository.Any(x => x.Id == id);

            if (exists)
            {
                return await func();
            }
            throw new Exception(errorMessage);
        }
```

Afterwards, you can consume it like this

```
await CheckLinkExistsAsync(1, "Custom Error Message", async () => {
  // DO STUFF AND RETURN
  var t = new T();
  return t;
});
```

Comment: The problem with the Db set is still there as I want to have _modelRepository passed in as parameter

Comment: @MaykalDroshev You don't say that in your question. Maybe you should show how this method that you're after should look like.